# Can we detect a photon's direction?

Tags: photons, particle-detectors

The question of if a photon even has a direction may be up for interpretation, but I wanted to know if it's possible for a device to absorb most light from every which direction and only detect light from one general direction, as well detect the wavelength of that photon.

The best analogy I can think of for this sort of device is how a stoplight can only be seen from one general direction and can't be seen from most other directions. In this case, it would be receiving photons rather than emitting photons.

Comment: When we measure the energy of an event, say detecting a gamma ray, we can work out the wavelength of the photons involved from that, is that what you mean?

Comment: And the same with the direction, if we point the telescope at a star, we can easily figure out the direction of the photons coming from the star, sorry, I am a bit lost here as regards your precise question...

Comment: Is the direction of a photon detected always from one specific direction or does it detect all photons coming from every direction that happen to hit the detector

Comment: CCD-camera or CMOS-camera, microlenses, optical devices. Conversion of photons into a displacement of electrons. Or photoemulsion film. Calorimeters. Multispectral cameras. Cooled infrared camera. ...

Comment: *"The question of if a photon even has a direction may be up for interpretation"* No more than any other particle (or even "particle").

Answer (score 1):

> The question of if a photon even has a direction may be up for interpretation,

I am not sure why you think that. If you look up at the Sun at midday, you'll sure know pretty quickly what direction the photons are coming from and you will probably turn your head to avoid looking in that direction.

> but I wanted to know if it's possible for a device to absorb most light from every which direction and only detect light from one general direction, as well detect the wavelength of that photon.

Take the detectors on space probes looking for gamma ray bursts. They would be much less useful if they could not tell us the direction of the burst. If other photons, with the same energy, happen to hit the detector at the same time, but from a different direction, that's not good, but it's unlikely. Any photons coming from different directions, but with less energy, are not a big  problem, usually,  to screen out.

If we know the energy of the electromagnetic radiation we have detected, it's no problem to work out the wavelength of the photons involved.